# Asp.net webservice call creating lot of threads in IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice which communicates with a desk top application using .Net remoting. The clients or users are using this webservice to insert or update any data to data base (through desk top application after some processing). The problem i'm facing is, during peaks time, that means calling 2000 - 3000 times this webservice to insert/update data with in 15 to 20 mins.. i can see that the number of threads increases upto around 2000. (In the TaskManager of w3wp.exe). What could be the possible reason for creating these much threads? As i can see other webservices are showing only less than 50 threads.

NB: The web service which is causing the issue is in a diff application pool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means many calls are waiting for response.
Since ASP.NET uses thread pool, you should use them for fast operations or instead use ASYNC handlers so the thread backs to the pool and ASP.NET assigns a new thread as soon as the result gets ready.

It can be result of deadlock in `BRL` or `DLL` or anything else. Try putting a break-point in web service code and find where it gets blocked.

Comment: The thread issue is only happening during the peak hours when we are having 2000 to 3000 request. The thread are under control when we are having request in 100's count. BTW.. The service is not doing any great job other than just rounting the request to the desk top application (its just a proxy)

Comment: @Anish: Probably the desktop application is the bottleneck. Those threads are waiting for desktop App response. You are creating and destroying the whole desktop application for each request. That's why old CGI applications have been replaced by smart web platforms.